# Minimum cuts on a rectangle to make into squares

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to solve this problem:

> Given an a×b rectangle, your task is to cut it into squares. On each move you can select a rectangle and cut it into two rectangles in such a way that all side lengths remain integers. What is the minimum possible number of moves?

My logic is that the minimum number of cuts means the minimum number of squares; I don't know if it's the correct approach.

I see which side is smaller, Now I know I need to cut bigSide/SmallSide of cuts to have squares of smallSide sides, then I am left with SmallSide and bigSide%smallSide. Then I go on till any side is 0 or both are equal.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int a, b; std::cin >> a >> b; // sides of the rectangle

    int res = 0;

    while (a != 0 && b != 0) {
        if (a > b) {
            if (a % b == 0)
                res += a / b - 1;
            else
                res += a / b;
            a = a % b;
        } else if (b > a) {
            if (b % a == 0)
                res += b / a - 1;
            else
                res += b / a;
            b = b % a;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    std::cout << res;

    return 0;
}
```

When the input is `404 288`, my code gives `18`, but the right answer is actually `10`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "*What am I doing wrong?*" - probably picked a wrong algorithm.

Comment: *What am I doing wrong?* -- Not working out the problem with pencil and paper before writing code.  The code writing phase should only occur after you have the plan done on paper first.  Otherwise you end up writing code, seeing it doesn't work, and possibly have to scrap the whole thing and start from scratch.

Comment: @Fureeish , I didn't even write "What am I doing wrong", someone edited it. But, you may be right, can you help me with the correct one?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I did do that, that's how I thought of how to approach the problem, the approach maybe wrong.

Comment: Imagine you cut your rectangle in "+" fashion. You will have 4 rectangles, but you've made only 2 cuts. So your logic is wrong.

Comment: @RadosławCybulski it's correct: "you can select a rectangle and cut it into two rectangles". The "+" would be 3 cuts, because after you make the first cut you have to select the top rectangle then the bottom one. Each cut you make increases the number of rectangles by one

Comment: @RadosławCybulski I don't think, that's how the problem works. suppose I have a rectangle, I need to cut it into 2 parts first. Then, I will work on separate parts one by one.e.g i have 3X5 rectangle, I need to cut firstly 1 3X3 square, totalCuts=1, then I will be left with 3X2 rect. then I cut 1 2X2 square out totCuts=2, then I will be left with 1X2 rectangle, I cut 2 1X1 sqaure, totCuts=3.

Comment: You seem to be right, i might have misunderstood the problem, thank you for explanation.

Comment: [Simpler counter-example to your algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yfr8B.png). The input rectangle is 21x10. Your method on the left with 11 cuts. A better solution on the right with 9 cuts

Comment: @user3386109 thanks for the visual explanation. much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems clear to me that the problem defines each move as cutting a rectangle to two rectangles along the integer lines, and then asks for the minimum number of such cuts. As you can see there is a clear recursive nature in this problem. Once you cut a rectangle to two parts, you can recurse and cut each of them into squares with minimum moves and then sum up the answers. The problem is that the recursion might lead to exponential time complexity which leads us directly do [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). You have to use [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) to solve it efficiently (worst case time `O(a*b*(a+b))`) Here is what I'd suggest doing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

int min_cuts(int a, int b, vector<vector<int> > &mem) {
    int min = mem[a][b];
    // if already computed, just return the value
    if (min > 0)
        return min;
    // if one side is divisible by the other, 
    // store min-cuts in 'min'
    if (a%b==0)
        min= a/b-1;
    else if (b%a==0)
        min= b/a -1;
    // if there's no obvious solution, recurse
    else {
        // recurse on hight
        for (int i=1; i<a/2; i++) {
            int m = min_cuts(i,b, mem);
            int n = min_cuts(a-i, b, mem);
            if (min<0 or m+n+1<min)
                min = m + n + 1;
        }
        // recurse on width
        for (int j=1; j<b/2; j++) {
            int m = min_cuts(a,j, mem);
            int n = min_cuts(a, b-j, mem);
            if (min<0 or m+n+1<min)
                min = m + n + 1;
        }
    }
    mem[a][b] = min;
    return min;
}

int main() {
    int a, b; std::cin >> a >> b; // sides of the rectangle

    // -1 means the problem is not solved yet, 
    vector<vector<int> > mem(a+1, vector<int>(b+1, -1));
    int res = min_cuts(a,b,mem);
    std::cout << res << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The reason the foor loops go up until `a/2` and `b/2` is that cuting a paper is symmetric: if you cut along vertical line `i` it is the same as cutting along the line `a-i` if you flip the paper vertically. This is a little optimization hack that reduces complexity by a factor of `4` overall.
Another little hack is that by knowing that the problem is that if you transpose the paper the result is the same, meaining  `min_cuts(a,b)=min_cuts(b,a)` you can potentially reduce computations by half. But any major further improvement, say a greedy algorithm would take more thinking (if there exists one at all).

Comment: As good the solution is and working fine. It's giving Time out for 499 500 cases. any minor improvements you could suggest?

Comment: @Behl yes, there is a hack, you can go until `a/2+1` and `b/2+1` in the for loops because of the symmetric nature of the problem, meaning you can flip the paper vertically or horizontally. I updated the code with this hack. On my machine `499 500` case runs in under a second, I guess that must be fast enough to pass the time limits.

Comment: The solution works fine. Also, how can I get the list of cuts that are being made along with minimum number of cuts? Is there a way we can do that?

Comment: @RoDev you cann add a second table like `best_cut` same size as `mem` where `best_cut[a,b]=('w',i)` or `best_cut[a,b]=('h',j)` means cut horizontally or vertically along `i` and `j` line respectively. Then you store these values while you're recursing

Answer (score 0):

The current answer is a good start, especially the suggestions to use memoization or dynamic programming, and potentially efficient enough.
Obviously, all answerers used the first with a sub-par data-structure. Vector-of-Vector has much space and performance overhead, using a (strict) lower triangular matrix stored in an array is much more efficient.
Using the maximum value as sentinel (easier with unsigned) would also reduce complexity.
Finally, let's move to dynamic programming instead of memoization to simplify and get even more efficient:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

constexpr unsigned min_cuts(unsigned a, unsigned b) {
    if (a < b)
        std::swap(a, b);
    if (a == b || !b)
        return 0;
    const auto triangle = [](std::size_t n) { return n * (n - 1) / 2; };
    const auto p = std::make_unique_for_overwrite<unsigned[]>(triangle(a));
    /* const! */ unsigned zero = 0;
    const auto f = [&](auto a, auto b) -> auto& {
        if (a < b)
            std::swap(a, b);
        return a == b ? zero : p[triangle(a - 1) + b - 1];
    };
    for (auto i = 1u; i <= a; ++i) {
        for (auto j = 1u; j < i; ++j) {
            auto r = -1u;
            for (auto k = i / 2; k; --k)
                r = std::min(r, f(k, j) + f(i - k, j));
            for (auto k = j / 2; k; --k)
                r = std::min(r, f(k, i) + f(j - k, i));
            f(i, j) = ++r;
        }
    }
    return f(a, b);
}
```